# Universal link not redirecting to iOS app

Tags: ios, safari, ios-universal-links, apple-app-site-association

I have done basic setup for universal linking

1. Associated domain is set applinks:domainName
2. Uploaded apple-app-site-association file to the server (tested in https://branch.io/resources/aasa-validator/). Updated new format to support iOS 13
3. Certificates are valid
4. Running in release mode
5. Added code for redirection in app

But still, on click of universal link, safari gets opened instead of iOS app (Not even a banner with OPEN button). Tried from notes app too .On long press of the link, my app is also not listed

Comment: Did you regenerate your Provisioning Profiles after enabling "Associated Domains" for you app ID?

Comment: yes I have done that